# getWritablePath() in cocos2d-x on Windows Phone gives weird results

Tags: windows, cocos2d-x, fileutils

I'm trying to get the writable path on Windows Phone in my game but `CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->getWritablePath()` always returns me results like "H??", "???", "??y".

I've already tried using this on cocos2d-x v2 and v3 with no luck.
Also I have tested this on Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 and 2014 Update 4.
It doesn't even work in clear project.

Is there any way I can fix this?